# Egg nog recommendation diabetic friendly

Tags: substitutions, recipe-scaling, sugar-free

How would you fine people make egg nog diabetic friendly? I’m inquiring as I’m diabetic myself & I have always liked the non-alcoholic version of egg nog during the holidays myself.

Comment: Milk itself contains a fair amount of sugars. You could make eggnog less unfriendly by using an artificial sweetener.

Comment: Makes sense to me @MaxW  but could you it in the form a actual answer though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eggnog can be easily adjusted for diabetics by removing as many carbs as possible. I recommend using heavy whipping cream and unsweetened almond milk, both of which have 1 or fewer net grams of carbs per serving. For a sweetener, I recommend using erythritol (or the brand name Swerve), as that is the only sweetener that I have come across that has [no effects on insulin](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8039489), blood sugar, or digestion. Here's a [low carb eggnog recipe](https://www.savorytooth.com/eggnog/) that only amounts to <0.5 g net carbs per serving (2/3 cup).

Comment: The recipe looks great!